# Buscar dados em um array se um dado especifico existir em outro

Tags: php, json

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Tenho 2 *arrays*:

```
teste [
        id: 20,
        campo: nada
        etc, 
        id: 30,
        campo: nada
        etc, 
]

teste 2 [
        id: 12, 
        nome: maria, 
        etc,
        id: 30, 
        nome: joão, 
        etc,
]
```

Todos os `ids` vão bater, ou seja, os `ids` do 1° *array* estão todos presentes no 2° *array*, porém fora de ordem e não dá pra ordenar porque isso vem de um JSON gerado aleatoriamente.

Eu preciso checar quando os `ids` forem iguais e se sim, criar uma nova chave no 1° *array* com o dado do campo `nome` do 2° *array*.

Eu fiz

```
foreach ($array1 as $teste) {
    if($teste['id']==$array2['id']) {
        $array1['nome'] = $array2['nome'];
    }
}
```

Não dá certo, pois os `ids` que não batem `$array1['nome']` fica em branco.

Existe alguma solução simples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você tem certeza que todos os `id` de `$array1` existem no `$array2`, você não precisa verificar se o `id` é igual, basta procurar o registro referente ao `id` em `$array2` e obter o valor de `nome`:

```
foreach ($array1 as $i => $teste) {
    // Retorna a posição em $array2 onde se encontra o id:
    $index = array_search($teste["id"], array_column($array2, "id"));

    // Obtém o nome:
    $name = $array2[$index]["nome"];

    // Define o nome no $array1:
    $array1[$i]["nome"] = $name;
}
```

Veja um exemplo:

```
$array1 = [
  ["id" => 1, "campo" => "nada 1"], 
  ["id" => 2, "campo" => "nada 2"],
  ["id" => 3, "campo" => "nada 3"]
];

$array2 = [
  ["id" => 2, "nome" => "Nome 2"], 
  ["id" => 3, "nome" => "Nome 3"],
  ["id" => 1, "nome" => "NOme 1"]
];

foreach ($array1 as $i => $teste) {
    // Retorna a posição em $array2 onde se encontra o id:
    $index = array_search($teste["id"], array_column($array2, "id"));

    // Obtém o nome:
    $name = $array2[$index]["nome"];

    // Define o nome no $array1:
    $array1[$i]["nome"] = $name;
}

var_export($array1);
```

A saída é:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'campo' => 'nada 1',
    'nome' => 'NOme 1',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 2,
    'campo' => 'nada 2',
    'nome' => 'Nome 2',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 3,
    'campo' => 'nada 3',
    'nome' => 'Nome 3',
  ),
)
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/KjWdZD).

**Referências**:

`array_search`: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-search.php

`array_column`: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-column.php

Comment: Perfeito Anderson Carlos Woss
muito obrigado